# Win32 console app and MFC library incompatible during release compile

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a win32 console application that uses some MFC functions (Cobject, Cstring etc), it compiles and runs without problem under debug mode using the following configs:

```
Configuration: Active(Debug) Platform: Active(Win32)
General->Use of MFC->Use MFC in a Static Library
C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library:Multi-threaded Debug DLL(/MDd)
```

However, when I tried to compile for **Release** mode (still Win32 platform) using the following configs, it starts to have problems:

```
Configuration: Active(**Release**) Platform: Active(Win32)
General->Use of MFC->Use MFC in a Static Library
C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library: **Multi-threaded (/MT)**
```

The problem is with the conversion between MFC's 'wchar_t *' to 'char *' and string literals to 'LPCTSTR' etc. But such problem is not happening when I compile it for 'Debug'!!!

I know I can employ things like the _T macro etc, but there are so many of them and these clearly worked under debug mode, so I am really hoping it just some simple flag(s) that I change in the properties to make it work for 'Release' mode compilation. Help?

Comment: `change 'Use MFC' to static or dynamic, both failed with errors` Failed with **what** errors? When working with Properties dialog, make sure you are modifying the right configuration - pay attention to the Configuration drop-down in the top left corner.

Comment: There are two settings: `General > Use of MFC` and `C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library`. The two must agree - either both using a DLL (aka shared library), or both using static library. For `Runtime Library` setting, you want the flavor that has "debug" in it for Debug configuration, and the flavor without "debug" for Release configuration.

Comment: In project properties for release configuration, set C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library to Multi Threaded (/MT)

Comment: @Lahiru: Igor has already given the correct answer: Both MFC and CRT libraries must agree, both on dynamic vs. static as well as the configuration (Debug or Release). Changing one without updating the respective other will produce problems similar to that described in this question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik@Lahiru@Lahiru: I have updated my question, it's more defined this time, could you help?

Comment: This sounds like you have different *Character set* settings for Release and Debug configurations. Make sure that *Project Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Character Set* is set to *Use Unicode Character Set* for all configurations.

Comment: @IInspectable: you are right, changing to 'Release' also changes the Character Set property to use Unicode instead of Multi-Byte. I changed that in Release mode and it is compiling!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks for the explanation about the need for matching Code Generation property and General > Use of MFC setting

Answer (score 0):

@llnspectable and @Igor Tandetnik gave the correct answer to my question.

In Visual Studio VC++ 2008, under debug mode, for Configuration Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Character Set property, it is 'Use Multi-Byte Character Set'

However, when i change compile mode to 'Release', it automatically changes that setting to 'Use Unicode Character Set'. Thus, creating incompatibility between MFC string classes and functions with normal string, i.e. char *

So, after i change to 'Release' mode, I made sure the Character Set property is Use Multi-byte character set. The project compiled successfully.

Also, since I have MFC class and functions in project, the 'Use of MFC' setting is 'Use MFC in a Static Library' to ensure necessary libraries are included.